# Could this simple circuit charge li-ions in parallel?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging, lithium-ion

My goal is to design a circuit that can reliably charge 3.7V li-ion batteries in parallel for extreme high current applications (think over 100 amps).  Normally, I would just buy a cheap li-ion balance board, but I can't find one that can handle the currents in any sort of compact form.
So I designed this fairly simple charging circuit:
[image]

Since each cell caps out at 4.2V, I could just supply them all 4.2V limited to 500mA charging current. Once each battery reaches 4.2V, it stops drawing current.  This would ensure that each battery gets to 4.2V without overcharging, right?

I've never seen a battery charger designed this way, so I'm assuming it has some sort of fundamental problem.  Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: How is your 500ma charger related to the 100 amps cited in your post? Why do you think the battery stops drawing current when it reaches 4.2V? You are also assuming that each battery will always have the same voltage acoss it as it charges which is not likely.

Comment: @Barry The 500mA is not related to the 100 amps.  500mA was chosen as a reasonable charging current.  The 100A is only when the batteries are being drained through the "Load".  As for the batteries stopping at 4.2V, if each battery is supplying the same voltage as the voltage source in the opposite polarity, I would expect the current to drop to zero for that battery.  At least, that's my understanding.

Comment: Cell current will start to reduce when 4.2V is reached. But first to arrive at 4.2v will trickle down for longer and thus be more highly charged. When a cell reaches 4.2v it is initially at roughly 90% charge and then trickles towards 100% at decreasing current.

Comment: 14 months on:  My previous comment applies, BUT: Floating LiIon cells AT 4.2V will (usually) damage and then destroy them. "Usually" has fewer exceptions than is usually considered prudent. 4.1V will generally be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lithium batteries are dangerous.  If you look at the application circuits on the datasheets for Li charge controllers (Linear Technology, Maxim, etc.), their complexity is a direct indication of this.  Incorrect charging current can cause the batteries to burst, burst into flame, or both.

There is nothing to assure that the charging current is distributed evenly among the cells.  If your idea is that as each cell reaches 4.2 V, it stops drawing current so the 500 mA is available to the other cells, know that lithium chemistry does not behave that way

The charge scheme you describe is common for lead-acid chargers, with a very simple transition from main to float or trickle charging.  Note that those chargers usually do not have a temperature sensor strapped to the side of the battery, whereas in Li systems this is very common.  I recently rebuilt a Dustbuster-style hand vacuum.  Five Li cells in two groups, 2 and 3 batteries.  Each group has its own thermistor, and battery management is handled by a PIC microcontroller.

Comment: Read about the details of a Li-Ion charger (that you are not using) at www.batteryuniversity.com . When a cell reaches 4.2V then it is no where near fully charged, it keeps charging but the charger must never allow the voltage to get higher than 4.2V and must disconnect when it senses a full charge. Do you have a circuit to sense a low voltage (3.0V per cell) then disconnect the battery?

Comment: Lithium-Ion are fairly safe, it's the Lithium Polymer that are dangerous. Chemistries have improved a lot in recent years and in our day, it's very rare to have a Li-Ion burning up, perhaps no more than lead-acid. Your vacuum probably used Li-Polymer.

Comment: If the cells don't stop drawing current when they get to 4.2V, then what do they do?  Do they keep drawing a current and stay at the same voltage?  Do they begin to heat up, even at a low charging rate of 500mA?  Surely, as the cells reach 4.25V they will stop drawing a current.

Comment: @DanielWilliams at the very least they will be damaged if you overcharge them.  Charging Lithium Ion batteries properly (Producing minimal wear per charge) requires a 2 stage charging process.  First constant current of 0.8 to 1C and then constant voltage charging until current falls to about 10% rated.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit would be fairly safe for Lithium-Ion as long as the 500mA source is lower than the maximum charge current allowed of any single battery, which is usually 1C.

Although the charge speed would be very slow.

Also, it's not good for Li-battery to remain charged at full capacity, this reduces their lifetime.

Lithium-Polymer would be more tricky, make sure of what chemistry you use.

Comment: Floating LiIon cells AT 4.2V will (usually) damage and then destroy them. "Usually" has fewer exceptions than is usually considered prudent. 4.1V will generally be safe.